# why oracle temporary more and more large?

Tags: oracle

I have a spring boot app with tomcat connection pool and oracle database.
It work for 7*24h and maybe connection is always exist and work.
Oracle temporary increase more and more large.It seems can not reduce or recovery.Only reduct used space not file size after I stop app.
Now the temporary file is 32GB and still not enough.
What should I do now?Restart app every day?

oracle snapshot:

[image: oracle snapshot]

```
`
MERGE INTO TABLE_ABC
USING 
(SELECT 
    1000000035432496 AS "ID",
    1000000035432496 AS "BID",
    sysdate AS "UpdateTime",
    sysdate AS "EntryTime",
    '2017-08-08' AS "AAA", 
    'ABCDEFG' AS "BBB"
FROM DUAL) T
ON (TABLE_ABC.ID=T.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE 
    SET BID=T."BID",
    UPDATETIME=T."UpdateTime",
    ENTRYTIME=T."EntryTime",
    AAA=T."AAA",
    BBB=T."BBB"
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ID,BID,UPDATETIME,ENTRYTIME, AAA, BBB) 
    VALUES(T."ID",T."BID",T."UpdateTime",T."EntryTime",T."AAA", T."BBB")
`
```

Comment: Temporary lobs are leaking somewhere in the session. If you don't want to   restart the session every now and then, you will have to trace sql statements and test suspicious ones in a rig for leaking.

Comment: "select 1 from dual" is to check validation query in connection pool.I use "MERGE INTO" sql to insert or update data.Is that the problem?

Comment: There are some sqls running in the session that utilize temporary lobs. 'Select 1 from dual' is not related to the problem. 'Merge into' statement per se is not the problem. If it uses temporary lobs directly or indirectly that might be it.

Comment: Excessive use of `select 1 from dual` points to poor architecture. Obviously that's not a query which requires a LOB, so the whole thing seems broken.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with all the comments on bad architecture.

If you insist on using lobs, leaks can be minimized by:

Adding checking if the lob exists before creating a new one

```
  if not (DBMS_LOB.ISOPEN(v_blob)) then 
    DBMS_lob.createtemporary(v_blob,true);
  end if;
```

and

```
dbms_lob.freeTemporary;
```

when you are finished using the lob.

It obviously depends how your app is accessing the lob.  Just remember to close the lob (handle) after using it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't understand very well. Some tables in my app with clob or blob fields.So maybe it use lobs. And I use "MERGE INTO " sql to insert or update rows.My app is a tool to transfer tables with multi threads http request.So it will create large numbers of sql for each row.I guess oracle can't reduce temporary when jdbc connection is hold.But sometimes temporary still very large after app be stopped.

Comment: In my experience if the dbms_lob.freeTemporary is not done, temp seg is not released.  In all other usages of temp seg, oracle releases temp if the app closes e.g. GTT and large sorts.  Large amount of SQL may use temp but should release it.  We cannot help any further unless you paste the MERGE statements sorry.