# Oracle TemporaryLobs causes Memory Leak

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, memory-leaks, blob, spring-jdbc

we have a problem with a Spring Boot application (Spring Boot 2.7.x) that uses Oracle 21c as datasource. During the execution, we run in a series of OoM caused by the use of Blob.

We have made some application dump, and the result is the following

[image]

We have seen how blob objects are persisted within the temporaryLobs list, which is managed directly by the Oracle driver. We do not have the possibility of interacting with this list using the Spring Jdbc (5.3.25) library that we use to interface with the Oracle database.

Anyone can help us?

Here's a fragment of our pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>19.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.nls</groupId>
    <artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
    <version>21.5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71664581/strange-memory-grow-in-temporarylobs-while-fetching-clob-with-oracle-jdbc-driver), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912145/why-oracle-temporary-more-and-more-large), or [this Oracle support document](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2297060_1.html). There's also [this Ask Tom article](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2957424542334) and [this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/jdbc-4-0s-lesser-known-clob-free-and-blob-free-methods/).

A short answer is that your Java code is not calling java.sql.Blob.free() when it's done with temporary lobs - and with connection pooling, the database sessions are never really destroyed, so all the lobs stay in memory until you restart your entire application. You need to explicitly free every temporary blob.

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion. Is there any way to impute, by working on properties, this behavior without having to make the free() method explicit in every Blob object access?

Comment: @MatteoRossi sorry, I don't know. But that's a great question, it would be a very handy way to work around this issue.